# Avoiding a repeated handler call

Tags: html, angular, events

I have the following in the html of an Angular project:

```
    <input type="text"
     class="whatever"
     (blur)="myEvent()"
     (keyup.enter)="myEvent()">
```

This works, but the repetition of "myEvent()" feels like a DRY violation. Is there a way to link both `blur` and `keyup.enter` to that event without repeating the call?

Comment: You should take care of your OCD problem first :)

Comment: I can't think of any way to do this that wouldn't be significantly messier than the normal way. Best to just deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment and the lack of another answer, I'm assuming the answer is "no, there is no way to do that."